# Why can the "status-completed" tag not be removed?

Tags: support, tags, meta, required-tags

Okay, I understand that on metaSO, (at least) one of the grey-bordered tags is required (bug, feature-request, discussion or support), and that the bold red-bordered tags (status-*) can only be added by a moderator. However, it used to be possible to *remove* a red-bordered tag from a post -- e.g. I did so on [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27234/account-last-activity-time-is-not-always-updated) to essentially mark it as "reopened -- bug still occurring". Why was this ability removed? It is now impossible to re-report a bug, as duplicate posts are a no-no.

FWIW, the post I wish to mark as "nope, still just as much a problem as before" is [this one regarding the reputation cap and downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2241/daily-reputation-cap-effectively-counts-downvotes-twice) (which I just encountered today).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're the owner of the first post, but not the second.

Comment: Why should that make a difference? I can't think of another example where the owner of a question can do something that anyone else (with sufficient reputation) can't do... except perhaps deleting a question which has no upvotes?

Comment: I don't think it should make a difference, but it seems like that is what may be going on.

Comment: A rollback (apparently) isn't subjected to the same tag rules as a regular edit, making it possible for the owner of a post to remove a mod tag.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, duplicate *discussions* are a no-no. If you can re-create a bug marked fixed, I see no reason why you shouldn't start a new thread... For all you or I know, it could be an entirely different problem that just happens to share symptoms with an earlier bug.

Just try to include enough information so that others can reproduce the problem as well, or it'll probably either get closed as a duplicate or simply tagged [`status-norepro`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-norepro)!

Comment: There have been so many posts regarding the broken reputation system that I don't see how it's going to add any value to create yet another one. I kind of suspect that Jeff intended to mark this one "status-I-don't-give-a-damn-and-it's-not-getting-fixed", which is too long of a tag but at least it's more honest.

Comment: Well, you might well be right... but in that case, you already have your answer.

Answer (score 3):

The moderator tags (red) can only be added or removed by moderators.