# Cannot remove the No-Repro status tag

Tags: support, moderator-tags

When trying to remove the no-repro tag, I get this message:

> Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted
>   because:
>
> the moderator tag 'status-norepro'
>   must be present

[This question on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72963/cannot-edit-a-post-after-a-mod-tag-was-added-to-it) indicates the same behaviour with a different tag, but the accepted answer to that question is that it is now fixed (to me indicating that the tag can be removed)...although now that I think about it, it could be interpreted that the edit is allowed even though the mod tag exists (leaning towards this one now)...Was going to use the Bug tag, but this wouldn't be correct now.

The question I want to remove the no-repro tag from is [this one I asked on meta.askubuntu.com](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1095/top-bar-style-for-ask-ubuntu) which I think is valid because I am able to reproduce the scenario on a different machine that is different to the original machine...

The reason I want to remove the tag is that I am still having the problem (on several machines) and that the no-repro tag will mean that the question will likely be dismissed by other readers.

The no-repro definition:

> Indicates that erroneous reported
>   behavior cannot be reproduced by the
>   developers, or can no longer be
>   reproduced by anyone.

Comment: Well, you're right that "status-completed" is often not helpful. One has to make educated guesses as to _what_ was completed. Here, it was completed that you can still _edit_ the question. (Can you?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To [quote Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30395/why-can-the-status-completed-tag-not-be-removed/31345#31345):

> The moderator tags (red) can only be added or removed by moderators.

If you really want it removed, flag the post for moderator attention. However, if the mods and devs can't reproduce it, it's not coming off.

Comment: That's what she said

Comment: At least there was recognition that it could be reproduced

Comment: `That's what she said` @jmfsg, I don’t get it; what part of that post was had a double entendre?

Comment: @Synetech "it's not coming off".  I agree it's pretty limp, and can see why it was a hard one to get, even by any stretch or stimulation of the imagination. I got it from Jack off the television, he did a recent stand-up sketch of it.