# The quest for reputation, badges and other useless flair decoration

Tags: feature-request

I've been a developer for about 5 years now. I'm counting the year I spent in college in these 5, because as far as my Stack Exchange (mainly Stack Overflow) experience goes, it's been about 5.

It's interesting how participating on Stack Overflow compares to the real-life experience of being a dev. I think a lot of devs out there can relate to my experience. You start off by asking the older devs for help, and by asking questions on SO which are either dupe or lack research. You burn yourself with the downvotes, and very quickly you take in the fear of asking stupid questions, and the "suck it up" attitude. Can't figure it out? Try harder. When you're really stuck, you learn to really document your question and your research, so as to avoid wasting the older dev's time, or getting downvotes on your question. You get the idea; maybe this is not every dev's experience but I'm confident a lot will have felt the same thing.

And this is all fine and dandy. You learn the rules, you learn to play by them. I thought I understood them, anyway, until quite recently when I started participating here a bit more regularly. (or shall we say: I know these rules are accurate in the real world scenario; I'm just not sure they're accurate on SO).

I come across a wide range of various profiles. Some users have about 5k reputation and still not a gold badge; their best is silver, "java". Some have 15k, with loads of gold badges, but their badges are all participation related. Some guys have 70 rep and gold badges for "famous questions". What kind of question? "Onclick() method not working in Internet explorer" - questions with potentially low reputation, but thousands of views from other beginners: boom, gold badge to your belt.

And most people who contribute to SO on a regular basis like having fancy badges and reputation. Hey, looks good on your flair, and can come in handy in a job search.

What I'm trying to say is, are we sure the reputation + badges system as it exists today truly represents what a mature developer should be? Can we find a way of valorising knowledge, and helping others, more than simple participation to the community (through editing, raising flags etc), and make that more valuable than a famous question? (a silver "java badge is worth more than a stupid "famous question" gold badge). Make answers more valorising than questions, yet without discouraging questions?

I hope I'm clear in sharing my thoughts here. It's not a request I've seen anywhere yet. Again, it's not about a specific badge, or number of points allocated to a specific action; it's about the image we give new comers in the community as to what the perfect developer should be.

Comment: I feel you greatly overestimate how much most other people care about badges, and personally I'd say you seem care about them way, way more than you should.  If you're participating here largely for the sake of badges, it's going to cause problems, both for you, and the site.

Comment: I think you missed the point of badges. They are a game for getting people to have good habits, that benefit the site and show knowledge of how a site works and other contributions, outside of Q/A

Comment: Your first three paragraphs are just entirely off topic.  If you're here to ask about changing what badges the site has then talk about that, not your history as a developer.  It's just wasting people's' time.

Comment: Fair enough! I guess the fact you both disagree with me justifies the downvotes, the way any community should work.

Comment: Personally I've learned a lot from contributing on Stack Overflow in particular. My motivations therefore are far from altruistic.

Comment: Dude, maybe just take some time and start reading through Jeff Atwood's blog Coding Horror where he talks about the site and what he is doing and why. He has some interesting other posts too, like the anatomy of an upvoted question or of a top user.

Comment: @rlb.usa Why not post that as an answer? That's the kind of discussion I'm looking to have on this post, regardless of all the downvotes. I honestly don't feel this was a bad or dumb question.

Comment: _"are we sure the reputation + badges system as it exists today truly represents what a mature developer should be"_ In fact, I think we're quite [sure that it doesn't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12335/is-reputation-too-subjective).

Comment: @Josh Caswell In that case, instead of downvoting, let's answer the question and make it clear for others who might think the same way as I do.

Comment: I mean, you've got two answers, and an upvote that mysteriously appeared at approximately the same time as my comment.

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing *recognition* with *achievement.* Up-voting a post (awarding reputation) is a simple way for a user to say "thanks, that's helpful". In aggregate, it's a useful filtering mechanism to sort the most-recognized stuff to the top. Happy coincidence.

But the numbers and little gold dots do not *define* what a developer should be. I can sit in my room and write my own little programs, or I can contribute to a worthy open source project selflessly to help others — employers are likely to appreciate the latter; Stack Overflow also has a purpose in that regard.

But to suggest these tokens are somehow harmful to new comers misrepresenting what a new programmer should be feels a bit like saying we should not give medals to soldiers because valor is not defined by a bit of colored ribbon you pin on your chest.

Most people know that. It's a given.

Answer (score 1):

Badges aren't always (sometimes they are, but often not) indicators of expertise. Yeah, a gold tag badge for [java](/questions/tagged/java) *probably* means that the user knows Java pretty well, but a Popular Question badge for a question tagged [java](/questions/tagged/java) might not. But that's not one of the upsides of badges; a big upside is that they, alongside reputation, provide a means of [gamification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamification) - an incentive for people to continue contributing content.

After a person's written a lot of answers, it can get a little bit boring, and maybe a a bit of a slog to keep at it. A perfect altruist who just wants to help people would keep hacking away and making the Internet a better place without needing anything, but not everyone's that perfect do-gooder. Most of us are here because we want to help other people or learn; that doesn't mean that a little extra incentive isn't sometimes needed.

Badges are one way to keep people motivated. I always view them as a little reward - an 'atta boy', if you will, from time to time. It's satisfying to get a Nice Answer badge, right? Doesn't that raise the dopamine levels in your brain a bit, and encourage you to keep on helping people? It does. And that's a good thing.

Of course, if a person's here *just* for the badges and reputation, their heart's not in it, and that's not a good thing. But those people don't always succeed in actually writing good posts, and so they don't end up getting the rewards they came for.

It's also worth noting that different badges are easier and harder to get on different sites. For instance, on small beta sites, getting 100 votes on a question might be nearly impossible, while on larger sites, it's certainly doable (albeit still challenging). It also varies on a case-by-case basis. Unfortunately, the system can't tell how impressive each achievement really is (and thus weight it accordingly, if you introduced even finer levels of achievement).

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. My point wasn't to get rid of badges, not at all. I entirely agree, a "nice answer" is nice to have and is rewarding. Not all badges require that much merit however, and to take the same example I mentioned in my answer, I think it's a bit of a shame that a famous question which hasn't been researched a lot is more "valuable" (gold) than a "java" (silver) which demonstrates deep understanding and knowledge.

Comment: @ChrisNeve Some famous questions *have* been researched a lot; this is sometimes the case in smaller site (i.e. non-SO), where asking a question that valuable is extremely difficult to do.

Comment: And that's fair enough. I'm not saying the current system is completely invalid; I just thought it would be interesting to discuss about this. I will admit I don't understand the negative feedback.